# Compiling som_pak (97) with present gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, som

I'm trying to use the original som implementation by Kohonen but I'm getting a segmentation fault error using vcal.

It turns out that you can use an unofficial version which corrects this error found at
http://cis.legacy.ics.tkk.fi/hynde/lvq/
but its from 1997, i'm sure that there are a lot of changes in cc compiler so I'm getting this error

```
    checo@canija:~/bin/som/som_pak-3.2$ make
    gcc -O2   -c -o vcal.o vcal.c
    In file included from datafile.h:28,
                     from vcal.c:26:
    fileio.h:69: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
    /usr/include/stdio.h:651: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
    make: *** [vcal.o] Error 1
    checo@canija:~/bin/som/som_pak-3.2$
```

The file datafile.h

```
    1:#ifndef SOMPAK_DATAFILE_H
    2:#define SOMPAK_DATAFILE_H
    ...
    24:#include 
    25:#include 
    26:#include "lvq_pak.h"
    27:#include "errors.h"
    28:#include "fileio.h"
```

Is there anything I can do to recomple this code?

Comment: [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is now a POSIX function; it wasn't in 1997.  Your best bet may be to rename the function in `fileio.h` and where it is used, maybe as simply as: `#undef getline` and `#define getline(a, b, c) som_getline(a, b, c)` in `fileio.h` before the appearance of `getline` and after the `#include <stdio.h>`. (Use the right number of parameters, or `#define getline(...) som_getline(__VA_ARGS__)`).  If `<stdio.h>` is not yet included, then add it to ensure that `getline()` is declared normally, then mapped by your macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting a comment to an answer to allow the question to be resolved.*</sup>

[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is now a POSIX function; it wasn't in 1997. Your best bet may be to rename the function in `fileio.h` and where it is used, maybe as simply as adding before the appearance of `getline` and after the `#include <stdio.h>`.

```
#undef getline
#define getline(a, b, c) som_getline(a, b, c)
```

Use the right number of parameters, or

```
#define getline(...) som_getline(__VA_ARGS__)
```

If `<stdio.h>` is not yet included, then add it to ensure that `getline()` is declared normally, then mapped by your macro.